# Concourse custom resource type failing in check step

Tags: concourse, concourse-pipeline, concourse-resource-types

I'm following below github repo for building a new concourse custom resource type in python.
https://github.com/apjansing/mongo_resource

But it is failing with below error in the resource check in concourse pipeline

```
run check step: check: Backend error: Exit status: 500,
  message: {
    "Type":"",
    "Message":"runc exec: exit status 1: exec failed: container_linux.go:380:
      starting container process caused: no such file or directory",
    "Handle":"",
    "ProcessID":"",
    "Binary":""
  }
```

My check file content is

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import json

if __name__ == "__main__":
  print(json.dumps([{"version": "1.0.0" }]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When saving the file from windows, the formatting was different hence the check file was not identified by the concourse resource running in Linux environment.

`dos2unix` utility can be used to convert the formatting of the file, it resolved my issue.

More details: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-fix-exec-user-process-caused-no-such-file-or-directory-in-docker

Answer (score 0):

I think this is simply telling you that it could not find the `check` script. It must be at `/opt/resource/check` and be executable.

See https://concourse-ci.org/implementing-resource-types.html for the official documentation; I keep it handy each time I am writing a Concourse resource.

Comment: It was actually caused due to file format from windows, dos2unix helped